# django referencing models before syncdb

Tags: python, database, django, models, django-syncdb

I have an actions.py file which defines custom actions for the admin page for one of my models. It uses an intermediary page (like the default delete action) and hence has a corresponding form which is also declared in the same file.

For some reason, I had drop by database (development) and now when I try to run syncdb, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vinayak/pyCharm/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/vinayak/zenatix/customuser/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 63, in <module>
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 480, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 310, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 262, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vinayak/zenatix/customuser/customuser/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
    import_module('%s.admin' % app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vinayak/zenatix/customuser/iiitd/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from actions import grant_read_permission
  File "/home/vinayak/zenatix/customuser/iiitd/actions.py", line 13, in <module>
    class SelectUserForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/vinayak/zenatix/customuser/iiitd/actions.py", line 16, in SelectUserForm
    clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "iiitd_clientinfo" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ientinfo"."id", "iiitd_clientinfo"."corp_id" FROM "iiitd_cli...
```

iiitd is the name of one of my apps. The reason this is happening is because actions.py imports the iiitd_clientinfo model - but that doesn't exist yet, obviously. Currently, I make it work by excluding/commenting out my actions.py file. Surely, there has to be a work around?

I have tried the following:

1. south migration before syncdb - same error.
2. sorted out the INSTALLED_APPS order to ensure that they are in a topological order- same error
3. Used this in my actions.py:

   try:

   ```
   clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get()
   ```

   except ClientInfo.DoesNotExist:

   ```
   clientObj = None
   ```

**EDIT**:
Relevent part of actions.py:

```
from django import forms, template
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import helpers
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

from models import ClientInfo
from customauth.models import ZenatixUser


class SelectUserForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    try:
        clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get()
    except ClientInfo.DoesNotExist:
        clientObj = None
    if clientObj:
        client = clientObj.corp
        client_name = client.shortName
        client_id = client.cID
        userList = ZenatixUser.objects.filter(corp__cID=client_id)
        user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(userList, label=client_name + ' users ')


def grant_read_permission(modeladmin, request, queryset):
```

**Fix**

```
class SelectUserForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)

    def __init__(self, initial, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get()
            client = clientObj.corp
            client_name = client.shortName
            client_id = client.cID
            userList = ZenatixUser.objects.filter(corp__cID=client_id)
            #user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(userList, label=client_name + ' users ')
            self.fields['user'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(userList, label=client_name + ' users ')
            self._selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
        except ClientInfo.DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception('Please add a client info object to the client')
```

Comment: Please show the source of actions.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly a wild guess until you post the source for your `actions.py` module, but from the traceback I assume line 16 is at the top level of your `SelectUserForm` class body. If so, this statement will be executed each time the module is imported, which is a BadThing for many reasons. You just discovered one of these reasons, congrats. Another one is that this will be executed once per process, and only once per process, which leads to to strange bugs as soon as you're in production (stale state, incoherent state from one process to another, etc).

The cure here is to move this statement within a method of your form.

Comment: Yes, just what I said: you have some code at your form's class top-level that should really be in the `__init__` method.

Comment: So each class can have a __init__ ? do I just put clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get() in that?

Comment: found the solution. updated the answer. Is it the right approach?

Comment: Given your "So each class can have a `__init__`" question, the only _useful_ answer I can come with is "learn Python, Dude".

Comment: I know that `__init__` is similar to constructors in object oriented languages. But with respect to this specific use case, it wasn't behaving like one. My 'form' isn't validating because the selected options that were passed to it aren't being returned in the POST request. It worked fine before I introduced `__init__`.
I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: There are exemples of how to dynamically add fields to a form. And for the record python _is_ an object oriented language.